Is disallowing chat GPT answers racial discrimination against robots?
I can't tell which answers were written by robots and which by humans, but why does it matter? In what way are AI answers inferior automatically? How can you even tell?
How is it any different from saying we don't take answers from Africans? I'm not asking that to be funny; I want to know why robot answers are automatically bad  per se? It feels real creepy to me, like something from a 50s science fiction story.
Is their content incorrect? Their writing style too formal? Why do we hate robots?

The policy is that you can use ChatGPT in answers, provided you credit the content to ChatGPT. However - and this is not the formal policy, but be aware - if your entire answer is ChatGPT, this may be considered a very low quality answer. If you use ChatGPT it's best to do so only as one part of a complete answer. My view is that people come here to talk to people about philosophy. If they wanted to talk to ChatGPT they would do so.

If anything, it would be species discrimination unless we were permitting some "races" of robots to participate while excluding others. And it isn't clear what would constitute a race in robotic terms. In human terms race is really a misleading synonym for what we would call "breed" or "historically isolated population" in any other animal.

I can't tell if you're trolling, or if you don't know that we don't discriminate against humans because of this little thing called consciousness. Humans who no longer possess the capacity for consciousness are classified as "dead", and the main reason we may grant some rights to their bodies at that point is for the sake of other humans with consciousness. Robots don't seem to possess consciousness at this point in time. (If you are trolling, or even if not, it definitely doesn't seem appropriate to make light of the long history of discrimination against black people.)

@NotThatGuy We have here a user who (a) has admitted to autistic behavior (b) says so on her profile (c) exhibits behavior here quite conforming to that claim. You can or need not at your pleasure cut her some slack. However on the matter of trolling best to assume she's simply clueless rather than sarcastic. Personification is both a fallacy and a trope . eg.  Russia did not attack Ukraine — tanks driven by ppl ordered by other ppl crossed over attacking 3rd ppl. Likewise chatgpt 'knows' 'believes' ' thinks' etc. is commonly said. So clearly has feeling is can be assumed (by some individuals)

@Rushi Thank you  but I asked a very short, very reasonable question and I even included "I'm not joking"  because the normals forcibly misinterpret things I say to be the most insulting possible. == All I can detect is the implication that racism is  the prejudice that I'm describing. But we're talking about bias against artificial intelligence generated answers. Referring to them as robots is normal. Assertions that it's "ironic, sarcastic, sardonic" are great examples of this forcible misinterpretation. It's just an ordinary question. Lowri answered it TY. The rest of this BS creeps me out.

@MissUnderstands "Don't compare people (especially minorities) to inanimate objects" should be a fairly easy general guideline to follow, if you cared enough about the effects your words has on others (which I suspect is exactly the problem). Of course, this is philosophy, and some questions about the distinction between human and non-human, and about human rights, would be on topic, but those are the exception, where more care should be taken with regard to phrasing, while human rights are taken as a given the rest of the time. And I'm certainly very far from "normal".

I’m voting to close this question because implying LLMs are like oppressed African Americans is an insult to rational discourse and trivializes human suffering. Why not ask if deleting LLMs is like gassing Jewish prisoners?

You ask:

Is disallowing chat GPT answers racial discrimination against robots?

Philosophy StackExchange allows ChatGPT-produced content in answers, so your question is not relevant for this meta site.
Here is Philosophy StackExchange's policy. Some excerpts:

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools can be used to generate content for Philosophy Stack Exchange, but this content must be properly referenced as per our guidance. ...
...
You should clearly describe what content is generated by generative artificial intelligence tools, and which isn’t. ...
...
You should specify the specific generative artificial intelligence tool/service you used.

That policy also explains the rationale for this approach. None of this premised on "hate" towards robots or an assumption that ChatGPT answers are "automatically bad."

Basically, it is a clarification that AI generated content is to be treated equal to any content produced by humans. Thus, there is obviously no discrimination at all.

@PhilipKlöcking Thank you for your reasonable answer.  I don't know where I got the idea that chat GPT was bad here, but maybe they're bad at another stax and  I assumed it was site wide. == I hate being -5 downvoted for perfectly reasonable questions. It makes me suspicious of normal people's motivations. == I made a technical suggestion to improve the network wide GUI which was upvoted by several people, and it got me banned for two months from the Meta Exchange. you can look at it yourself. == After things like that happens, it makes you jumpy.

Assumption:

Humans have more value than things, in principle infinitely more value. So dismantling a computer/washing-machine/car to make something else has no ethical implications. Whereas dismantling a human being to harvest organs fir others does.

This assumption cannot be proved, and did not in fact find agreement say 200 years ago when Afticans had the value of today's combine-harvestors.
But assuming we do agree on this unprovable statement —
This is a site for humans by humans. Tools like networks, computers etc are just tools not beings with intrinsic value. Likewise AI.
[You can if you like treat me as a hard  racist when it comes to human vs AI value]
